# Mapping Alt + Up to PgUp

Tags: keyboard

I am using an application that has important operations mapped to the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> keys, but my keyboard doesn't have these keys (I'm using a ChromeBook Pixel 2015, running Linux Mint 18.2). I know I can map a certain keycode to the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> keysym using `xmodmap`, but I can't give up any other keys permanently.

Is there a way to map the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to <kbd>PgDown</kbd>? Is there a better way to achieve this?

EDIT: I have used the command `xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = 0xff52 0xff55"` to set <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> to <kbd>PgUp</kbd> but I am still interested in a general solution.

Comment: Are you using ChromeOS or another OS?  With ChromeOS, search+uparrow is the default for page up/down

Comment: There you go buddy: https://codereview.chromium.org/3364001/diff/1/x11-misc/xkeyboard-config/files/xkeyboard-config-1.7-nav-keys.patch